# Where is the database for feedreader?

Tags: programming, database, sql, sqlite, rss

It's implied:

[https://code.launchpad.net/~eviltwin1/feedreader/sqlite](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eeviltwin1/feedreader/sqlite)

that `feedreader` uses `sqlite` or that it can be configured to do so.

I looked in the `.config` folder, but didn't see anything specific to `feedreader`, nor did I see anything in the home folder.

If there's an `sqlite` or other database, how is it directly accessed?

Answer (score 0):

it's in `.local` like `liferea` is:

```
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ pwd
/home/nicholas/.local/share/feedreader/data
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ ll
total 1004
drwxrwxr-x 3 nicholas nicholas    4096 Sep 18 14:06 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 nicholas nicholas    4096 Sep 17 10:35 ../
drwxrwxr-x 3 nicholas nicholas    4096 Sep 17 23:57 feed_icons/
-rw-r--r-- 1 nicholas nicholas 1011712 Sep 18 13:49 feedreader-7.db
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ sqlite3 feedreader-7.db 
SQLite version 3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> 
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "feeds"
            (
                "feed_id" TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "url" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "category_id" TEXT,
                "subscribed" INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
                "xmlURL" TEXT,
                "iconURL" TEXT
            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "categories"
            (
                "categorieID" TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                "title" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "orderID" INTEGER,
                "exists" INTEGER,
                "Parent" TEXT,
                "Level" INTEGER
            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "articles"
            (
                "articleID" TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                "feedID" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "title" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "author" TEXT,
                "url" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "html" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "preview" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "unread" INTEGER NOT NULL,
                "marked" INTEGER NOT NULL,
                "date" INTEGER NOT NULL,
                "guidHash" TEXT,
                "lastModified" INTEGER,
                "contentFetched" INTEGER NOT NULL
            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "tags"
            (
                "tagID" TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                "title" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "exists" INTEGER,
                "color" INTEGER
            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "CachedActions"
            (
                "action" INTEGER NOT NULL,
                "id" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "argument" INTEGER
            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Enclosures"
            (
                "articleID" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "url" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "type" INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(articleID) REFERENCES articles(articleID)
            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "taggings"
            (
                "articleID" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "tagID" TEXT NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(articleID) REFERENCES articles(articleID),
                FOREIGN KEY(tagID) REFERENCES tags(tagID)
            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'fts_table_segments'(blockid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, block BLOB);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'fts_table_segdir'(level INTEGER,idx INTEGER,start_block INTEGER,leaves_end_block INTEGER,end_block INTEGER,root BLOB,PRIMARY KEY(level, idx));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'fts_table_docsize'(docid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, size BLOB);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'fts_table_stat'(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value BLOB);
CREATE INDEX "index_articles"
            ON "articles" ("feedID" DESC, "unread" ASC, "marked" ASC)
        ;
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts_table
            USING fts4 (content='articles', articleID, preview, title, author)
/* fts_table(articleID,preview,title,author) */;
sqlite> 
sqlite> .quit
nicholas $
```